# Retaining next n rows and previous k rows with pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas

I am merging two dfs and would like to access the first n rows of column after matching.

Where there is a match between `events_df['event']` and `prices_df['date']`

and also a match between

`events_df['ticker']` and `prices_df['tic']`

I would like to retain the first n values after and including the matched row from `prices_df['price']`

```
events_df

  event ticker
0 01-01-2019  MSFT 
1 12-12-2018  MSFT 
2 12-11-2018  MSFT   
3 02-03-2019  AAPL 
4 12-12-2018  AAPL 
5 12-11-2018  AAPL 
6 01-01-2019  AAPL 


prices_df

  date tic price 
0 01-01-2019 MSFT 1.0
1 02-01-2019 MSFT 1.1
2 03-01-2019 MSFT 1.2
3 04-01-2019 MSFT 1.3
4 05-01-2019 MSFT 1.4 
5 01-01-2019 AAPL 2.0
6 02-01-2019 AAPL 2.1
7 03-01-2019 AAPL 2.2
8 04-01-2019 AAPL 2.3
9 05-01-2019 AAPL 2.4
```

I've already tried merging

```
merged = events_df.merge(prices_df,left_on=['ticker','event'],right_on=['tic','date'])
```

Expected output for n = 4 (from matching `events_df['events']` index 0,6)

```
  date ticker price
0 01-01-2019 MSFT 1.0
1 02-01-2019 MSFT 1.1
2 03-01-2019 MSFT 1.2
3 04-01-2019 MSFT 1.3
4 01-01-2019 AAPL 2.0
5 02-01-2019 AAPL 2.1
6 03-01-2019 AAPL 2.2
7 04-01-2019 AAPL 2.3
```

Comment: What is expected output - DataFrame?

Comment: have updated q -

Comment: was referring to 'next' n rows in q. Have updated to 4. There are two matches between `events_df` and `prices_df` these are for index 0 and 6 in `events_df`

Comment: In sampled data are 3 rows matched.

Comment: you're right, my mistake, supposed to include two - updated to 2

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#changed sample data for more general
print (prices_df)
          date   tic  price
0   01-01-2018  MSFT    1.0
1   01-01-2019  MSFT    1.0
2   02-01-2019  MSFT    1.1
3   03-01-2019  MSFT    1.2
4   04-01-2019  MSFT    1.3
5   05-01-2019  MSFT    1.4
6   01-01-2019  AAPL    2.0
7   02-01-2019  AAPL    2.1
8   03-01-2019  AAPL    2.2
9   04-01-2019  AAPL    2.3
10  05-01-2019  AAPL    2.4

#n to down, k to up
n = 2 
k = 1
#get index by reset_index for avoid lost it
idx = events_df.merge(prices_df.rename_axis('idx').reset_index(),
                         left_on=['ticker','event'],
                         right_on=['tic','date'])['idx']

print (idx)
0    1
1    6
Name: idx, dtype: int64
```

---

```
#create groups by matching with original index, [::-1] for change ordering
s1 = prices_df.index.isin(idx).cumsum()
s2 = prices_df.index.isin(idx)[::-1].cumsum()

#repalce first and last groups to NaNs 
up = np.where(s1 != 0, s1, np.nan)
lo = np.where(s2[::-1] != 0, s2[::-1] , np.nan)

#get couters compare by le (<=) and remove NaNs groups (first, last)
prices_df['um'] = prices_df.groupby(up).cumcount().le(n) & ~np.isnan(up)
prices_df['lm'] = prices_df.groupby(lo).cumcount(ascending=False).le(k) & ~np.isnan(lo)
print (prices_df)
          date   tic  price     um     lm
0   01-01-2018  MSFT    1.0  False   True
1   01-01-2019  MSFT    1.0   True   True
2   02-01-2019  MSFT    1.1   True  False
3   03-01-2019  MSFT    1.2   True  False
4   04-01-2019  MSFT    1.3  False  False
5   05-01-2019  MSFT    1.4  False   True
6   01-01-2019  AAPL    2.0   True   True
7   02-01-2019  AAPL    2.1   True  False
8   03-01-2019  AAPL    2.2   True  False
9   04-01-2019  AAPL    2.3  False  False
10  05-01-2019  AAPL    2.4  False  False
```

---

```
#filter by boolean indexing
mask = prices_df['um'] | prices_df['lm'] 
prices_df = prices_df[mask]
print (prices_df)
         date   tic  price     um     lm
0  01-01-2018  MSFT    1.0  False   True
1  01-01-2019  MSFT    1.0   True   True
2  02-01-2019  MSFT    1.1   True  False
3  03-01-2019  MSFT    1.2   True  False
5  05-01-2019  MSFT    1.4  False   True
6  01-01-2019  AAPL    2.0   True   True
7  02-01-2019  AAPL    2.1   True  False
8  03-01-2019  AAPL    2.2   True  False
```

Comment: this returns `KeyError: 'index'` when I test on my data

Comment: @W.R - what is `print (prices_df.index)` ?

Comment: `Int64Index([     0,      1,      2,      3,      4,      5,      6,      7,
                 8,      9,
            ...
            603598, 603599, 603600, 603601, 603602, 603603, 603604, 603605,
            603606, 603607],
           dtype='int64', length=1168357)`

Comment: @W.R - Ok, then changed solution `idx = events_df.merge(prices_df.rename_axis('idx').reset_index(),
                         left_on=['ticker','event'],
                         right_on=['tic','date'])['idx']` should working

Comment: is it possible to tweak to include previous k rows also? (updated q title to reflect)

Comment: @W.R - Sure, give me some time.

Comment: @W.R - Not easy, please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Your merging looks okay. You just have to extract desired columns from it, because right after merging it contains all columns from both DataFrames. So:

```
merged = events_df.merge(prices_df, left_on=['ticker', 'event'], right_on=['tic', 'date'])
merged = merged['date', 'picker', 'price']
```

Then you have to filter it, so the price is less than 3 (or `n` if you want):

```
n = 3
merged = merged[merged['price'] < n]
```

Comment: Small advice - solution is wrong and it should be seen if add output to answer. There is necessary n rows after matched ones, here 3 rows after `0` and `5` index rows.